# Undefined properties in Angular expression binding

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a binding `{{getCategoryName(post.categories[0])['name']}}` where I need to process the value `post.categories[0]` returned in the `*ngFor` loop with a method `getCategoryByName()` in my component before finally binding it to the template.The method returns an  `Object`.

I keep getting the error `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` . I have tried getting the property using the `['name']` key instead of `.name` but still get the error.

Any thoughts for a workaround?

```
  <ion-item text-wrap class="news-item" *ngFor="let post of posts" (click)="viewStory(post)">
          <div >
          <p>{{getCategoryName(post.categories[0])['name']}}</p>
          <h2>{{post.title.rendered}}</h2>
          <p>By Fitz &middot; {{post.date | fromNow}}</p>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
```

The method

```
  getCategoryName(categoryId) {
    return this.categories[this.categories.findIndex((el)=>{ return el.id == categoryId})];
  }
```

Example ember of the `Array` from which the `Object` is returned by method above

```
[
  {
    "id": 33,
    "count": 1,
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co/category/apps/",
    "name": "Apps",
    "slug": "apps",
    "taxonomy": "category",
    "parent": 0,
    "meta": [],
    "_links": {
      "self": [
        {
          "href": "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/33"
        }
      ],
      "collection": [
        {
          "href": "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co/wp-json/wp/v2/categories"
        }
      ],
      "about": [
        {
          "href": "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co/wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/category"
        }
      ],
      "wp:post_type": [
        {
          "href": "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?categories=33"
        },
        {
          "href": "http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.co/wp-json/wp/v2/jobs?categories=33"
        }
      ],
      "curies": [
        {
          "name": "wp",
          "href": "https://api.w.org/{rel}",
          "templated": true
        }
      ]
    }
  },

]
```

Comment: show the body of `getCategoryName` and the structure of `posts` array

Comment: @BougarfaouiElhoucine  I've edited to show the structure the object (Just one entry for brevity) and the method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply do like this

```html
{{getCategoryName(post.categories[0])?.name}}
```

`?` is the safe navigation operator. It checks whether the variable is null or undefined so that our template won't try to select a property of something falsy.

More info: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths

Comment: Marked as answer as this seems a more Angular way.

Answer (score 1):

In your getCategoryName method check if post.categories is undefined, and then return object {name : ''}:

```
if (post.categories === undefiend) { 
return {name : ''}
}
```

or you could use in template:

```
{{(getCategoryName(post.categories[0]) || {name : ''})['name']}}
```